# Ghost touch problem with my Lenovo A3300?

Tags: touchscreen

It seems to be happening randomly. There are times where I can use it without any problems occurring and there are times where I can't even scroll properly due to that one spot of the screen getting spammed with random touches. It's honestly driving me nuts!

I know which place the ghost touches are happening as I've turned on the "Show Touches" option in the settings but how can I fix it? Does the screen need to be replaced or something?

Comment: So called Ghost touch remedies on Play Store are generally ineffective. Best is to get professionally checked up and replace screen

Comment: See this supporting my view https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-fix-the-ghost-touch-problem-on-any-android-device